# Find out two point position in Google Map iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps

If I have two `GMSMarker` points: Points A,B on google map.

How can I rotation `A`'s way heading to `B`, and find out degrees between `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Geometry Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Geometry). This library provides utility functions for the computation of geometric data on the surface of the earth. `Spherical` is suitable to your concern, since it allowing you to compute angles, distances and areas from latitudes and longitudes. You need to add the library to the API call like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry
```

Then use the computeHeading method:

```
var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(pointA, pointB);
```

where pointA and pointB are the two LatLng objects.